# Invalid Template Control Keyword

Tags: terraform, aws-glue, terraform-template-file

Currently developing a TF template inclusive of some glue services. When attempting to init the template, I am prompted with the below error:

```
Error: Invalid template control keyword

on main.tf, in resource "aws_glue_classifier" "SrcPlanClassifier":
grok_pattern   = "%{DATA:col},%{DATA:col2},%{DATA:col3},"%{DATA:col4}",% . 
{DATA:col5},%{DATA:col6},%{DATA:col7},%{DATA:col8},%{DATA:col9},%{DATA:col10},% . 
{DATA:col11},%{DATA:col12},%{DATA:col}13$"

"DATA" is not a valid template control keyword.
```

This template is the result of translating an existing CloudFormation template to Terraform, so the pattern has worked in the past. From what I can tell in the AWS documentation for Glue, the DATA term is an acceptable built-in classifier.  That implies to me that this is an issue on the Terraform end. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to escape the `%` sign by doubling it up.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yep, figured this one out after some playing around.  Thanks for providing the correct answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Terraform is understanding the `%{` sequences as introducing a [template directive](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#directives), which then fails because `if` and `for` are the only keywords that are allowed to follow that `%{` marker in the Terraform language.

To use `%{` literally in your string, you can write `%%{` instead to escape the introducer. Terraform will see `%%{` and produce `%{` in the resulting string:

```
grok_pattern   = "%%{DATA:col},%%{DATA:col2},%%{DATA:col3},"%%{DATA:col4}",% . 
{DATA:col5},%%{DATA:col6},%%{DATA:col7},%%{DATA:col8},%%{DATA:col9},%%{DATA:col10},% . 
{DATA:col11},%%{DATA:col12},%%{DATA:col}13$"
```

(I think there were some line-wrapping problems in the message you shared so I've updated it as best I could for the escaping but you may need to do some additional escaping yourself. The general idea is to replace every `%{` with `%%{` in your quoted string.)

---

Another option, for complicated expressions whose readability is hurt significantly by this much escaping, is to move the relevant string into a separate file and then have Terraform read that file:

```
  grok_pattern = file("${path.module}/grok_pattern.txt")
```

The `file` function just takes the text in the given file verbatim, and does not parse it for template sequences or any other special markers.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above, the problem was indeed regarding escaping those characters.  Thank you for your verbose guidance and I'll look into using a separate file for these expressions in the future.